# If cell = #N/A, use another vlookup

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, vlookup

I have this Excel VBA macro which runs really well

```
    Sub PCMSLookupTool()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    With Sheets("Lookup Tools")   '<-set this worksheet reference properly
        LastRow = .Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range("J10:J" & LastRow)
          .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A10, 'PCMS-dump'!A:B, 2, FALSE)"
          .Cells = .Value2
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

But I need to make it so if it does not find a value (returns #N/A) to run another vlookup ("=VLOOKUP(A10, 'Imported in PCMS'!A:C, 3, FALSE)"

How would I go about to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is an IFERROR statement:

```
.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A10, 'PCMS-dump'!A:B, 2, FALSE),(VLOOKUP(A10, 'Imported in PCMS'!A:C, 3, FALSE)))"
```

Answer (score 1):

After your calculate that formula, you need to run something like this:

```
=if(isna(Sheets("Lookup Tools").Range(J10:J" & LastRow).Value),vlookup(A10,'Imported in PCMS'A:C,3,false),Sheets("Lookup Tools").Range(J10:J" & LastRow).Value)
```

I've always preferred to use another cell, else you end up running your first vlookup twice ...
ie:

```
=if(isna(vlookup1(...)), vlookup2(...),vlookup1(...))
```

which isn't terribly efficient ;)